# Is there a way to use Microsoft Advertising in a Desktop App that im developing in VS2019?

Tags: ads, desktop-application

My question is... is there a way to use Microsoft Advertising in a desktop application as in the UWP format? Im developing the app in VS2019. Please enlight me.

Answer (score 0):

For those with the same question here is the ansewr. 
The Advertising control included in the Store SDK is a Windows 10 control (targeting the Universal Windows Platform), so out of the box it can’t be used in a Windows Forms application.
A potential solution is to leverage XAML Islands, which is a technology recently introduced to allow hosting UWP controls inside Win32 applications. You can find all the implementation details here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands

The right thing to do is to develop your app in UWP. Maybe Microsoft will implement this feature in the future, but...